# Camera stops recording (but doesn't crash)

Tags: camera, video-recording

(Phone: Samsung Galaxy A5 (2017))

Since a few months back, every time I try to record a video with my default camera app or any other third party app, what happens is the following:

1. I start the recording.
2. A timer starts at the bottom with a blinking red light to indicate that the phone is indeed recording.
3. In a random amount of time (half a minute up to 3 minutes) the red light disappears, the timer stops, but the camera doesn't crash or anything - it just stays frozen and stops recording. I have to exit the app and reenter to get it working again.

Additional details:

- Photos I can take just fine.
- The problem doesn't seem to affect Snapchat or Google Meet, which I both regularly use.
- Yes, the problem also occurs with the front camera.
- When I tried to record on another application, when it stopped recording it stated "Failed to reconnect to camera" and "Server died, video halted".

What I have tried so far (and not one has worked):

- Deleting app data/cache
- Restarting my phone
- Changing between SD and internal storage for the saving location
- Going into safe mode
- Factory restarting my phone twice - once after I had restored everything, second time when the first thing I did after setting up my phone was going into the camera app to record.

I'm unsure if this is the right place for this question, but any help at this point would be much appreciated, as I'm in a big need for a recording device currently. Thanks!

Comment: In safe mode, does the stock camera work as it should?

Comment: Nope, still stops the recording process, even after the factory reset.

Comment: Did you check if the hardware (Camera) is OK? There are many apps on Play Store for "hardware tester", "phone tester" or "camera tester". This one is [specific to Samsung](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=trunghieu.tnt.samsungdevicetest). Maybe more. This is also a general purpose good app for Samsung https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo